# PHP: Stay on the same page when performing an action

Tags: php

I am trying to find a way to make a password enter form without changing the page.
Right now I am using it like this:

Enter:

```
<form action="developer.php" method="post">
<p>Password:</p><input type="password" name="password"/><br>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

developer.php:

```
<?php
$input = $_POST["password"];
if ($input != "mySecretPassword"){
header("Location: site/develop.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

And underneath de code from above the code to draw the whole page.

But I would like to stay at the same page (develop.php) instead of redirecting to developer.php, how should I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Accept answers so that users may answer to your question. To accept an answer, tick the most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use AJAX. It will help you achieve this. AJAX with jQuery is widely used to achieve aschnchrnymous loading. You can learn ajax here - > http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp . Your code for the jQuery will be :-

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.post("developer.php",
  {
    password:$("#pass-field").val(),
  },
  function(data,status){
   alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
});
```

Comment: It's looking good, but what excactly do I have to remove in my code and replace with yours? And could you please explain what each line means? I've looked ad the jQuery and AJAX tutorials, but I can't really 'read' it yet.

Comment: @user3142900 , you have to read the tutorials for understanding AJAX. If you do not know about jQuery, first learn that. jQuery makes the task of javascript short. AJAX involves big processes but jQuery has simplified it. It loads the "developer.php" page for you on the same page by sending POST/GET data to it. Eg-> If the output in the developer.php is <?echo "<script>window.location='abc.html';</script>" ?> and you use the data in the develop.php as $("body").append(data); (in the function given in my answer), then the page will be redirected to abc.html. I hope you got it. AJAX is vast.

Answer (score 0):

The action="developer.php" is forwarding you off the page.  Put the logic in the developer.php file on the $_post handler.

At the very top of your page put

```
<?
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // stuff from your developer.php file
        // The logic that compares the input to the password on file
    }
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
. . . . . .
```